# What happens when viewing an object that has a record type you don't have access to

Tags: rest-api, custom-object, page-layout, profile, record-type

I have a custom object named *Assessment* that has a RecordType field. What happens in Salesforce if I create an Assessment with a RecordType that others do not have access to (based on their profile). What will they see when loading the data for that particular Assessment I created? Will they be able to see it?

*Note: I'm using the Salesforce Rest API and wondering how to handle this situation.*

**Edit:** By what will they see, I'm curious what layout will they see it under? (As well as any other info you can provide on the matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the user cannot create records with a RecordType which they are not assigned but they would still be able to see records of any RecordType.

> Note
>
> Any user can view records having any record type, even if the record
>   type is not associated with their profile.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_recordtype.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you @jibernett530. I'm curious also which layout they will see? Especially if a user has multiple record types available to them (but not access to the recordtype in which the Assessment was saved under)

Comment: They are still assigned a page layout to each recordType even if that recordType isn't available to them.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the recordType that they don't have access to will still be used to display the object. Doesn't that seem odd?

Comment: You are correct, and it is necessary because the recordType although they can't select it is still viewable to them so the system needs to know how they should view it. So if you had top secret record type you could create a top secret for newbsd layout which doesn't display anything but a visualforce page telling them they do not have the access level to view the record.